# Handle list index out of range in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
det = soup.find_all('div', class_= 'player-data-personal-info')  
PlayerDetailsResult.extend([
    {                                
            d[0].text.strip(): d[1].text.strip(),
            d[2].text.strip(): d[3].text.strip(),
            d[4].text.strip(): d[5].text.strip(),
            d[6].text.strip(): d[7].text.strip(),
            d[8].text.strip(): d[9].text.strip(),
            d[10].text.strip(): d[11].text.strip(),
            d[12].text.strip(): d[13].text.strip(),
            d[14].text.strip(): d[15].text.strip(),
            d[16].text.strip(): d[17].text.strip(),
            d[18].text.strip(): d[19].text.strip(),
            d[20].text.strip(): d[21].text.strip(),
            d[22].text.strip(): d[23].text.strip(),
    }
    for d in (d.find_all(recursive=False) for d in det)  

])
j = j+1
```

How I can check if d length or d[index] is available or not?

Comment: Please edit the __full__error message into your question so it’s possible to see what line you get the error. You will probably have to use a `for` loop instead of a one-liner generator/comprehension, i.e. a loop which works with `len(d)` - and then you’ll be able to debug the loop if it doesn’t quite work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the indices instead:

```py
for d1 in det:
  for d2 in d1.find_all(recursive=False):
    result = {}
    for i in range(0, len(d2), 2):
      key = d2[i].text.strip()
      val = d2[i+1].text.strip()
      result[key] = val
    PlayerDetailsResult.append(result)
```